# Ubuntu 14.04 can't enable .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2, ubuntu

I'm developing a website local and just switched from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04 - Sadly my .htaccess doesn't seems to work since rewrite rules don't apply and sources can't be found.

I activated:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

rewrite_rule (shared) is listed via:

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
```

My website files (including my .htaccess) are located under

```
/var/www/html
```

My .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Hide Index
IndexIgnore *

# Forbid accessing certain sites
RedirectMatch 403 ^/.gitignore$
RedirectMatch 403 ^/.htaccess$
RewriteRule ^(?!index)(?!.*functions).*\.(php|rb|py|txt|md|sql|inc)$ - [F,L,NC]

# Remove 'php' folder in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ php/$1.php [L] 

# Hide .php file ending in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Alter "php" in url to "site"
#RewriteRule ^site/(.*) php/$1

# Manage Access-Control-Allow-Origin
#Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://blockchain.info"

# Enabling GZIP Compression
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

My /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# Include phpmyadmin
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

My etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Directory "/var/www">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I also applied rights via

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
```

and restarted apache via

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but also restarted the computer at some point.

After all this .htaccess still won't get loaded, so what have I forgotten?

Comment: Can you confirm whether it's really `.htaccess` or just mod_rewrite that isn't working? Which version of Apache?

Comment: `AllowOverride All` should be what makes *htaccess work*.  I would try matching the directory containing that to the document root:  `<Directory "/var/www/html">`

Comment: You only want one `<Directory "/var/www">`. For simplicity, pick one and stick with that, otherwise, Apache will take the last one seen. Since the apache2.conf has the directive out of the box and 000-default.conf does not, I suggest sticking with that one, however, if you feel it is easier to remember to edit 000-default.conf, then use that one. Comment one or the other. As well, `<Directory "/var/www">` is correct. it will cover the /var/www/html/ directory as well. This should be all you have to do unless there is a module that is not enabled such as mod_rewrite. Check your error log.

Comment: BTW- You should change Indexes to -Indexes for security reasons. If you chose to use -Indexes, you likely will have to change FollowSymLinks to +FollowSymLinks or Apache will fail to start.

Comment: Consider that when Apache starts up, it applies directives in the order found. This would be apache2.conf => 000-default.conf => .htaccess. Configuration files require restarting Apache. Some directives require restarting Apache. Your .htaccess file should only contain those directives that do not require a restart and you may need to change without a restart. Typically, these are things such as redirects.

Comment: Enable LogLevel debug in apache2.conf, restart apache, and check your error logs after loading a page again.